# why i can't using this code in CALLBACK Function?

Tags: c++, mfc

i hope to change static text but i can't,

```
LRESULT CALLBACK KeybdProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if ((nCode == HC_ACTION) && (wParam == WM_KEYDOWN))
    {
        KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT *pKey = (KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam;
        int key = pKey->vkCode;
        cout << key << " ";
        if (key == VK_INSERT)
        {
        SetDlgItemText(IDC_STATUSTEXT, "On")
        }
        if (key == VK_DELETE)
        {
            SetDlgItemText(IDC_STATUSTEXT, "Off")
        }
    }
CallNextHookEx(KbHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
return 0;

}

HHOOK KbHook;

BOOL CUSBDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialog::OnInitDialog();

SetDlgItemText(IDC_STATUSTEXT, "Successfully Loaded!!!");

cout << "Successfully Loaded !!!" << endl;
SetIcon(m_hIcon, TRUE);
SetIcon(m_hIcon, FALSE);

HMODULE hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
KbHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, KeybdProc, hInstance, 0);

return TRUE;

}
```

the error "function does not take 2 parameters"

can i fix it?

and can i using this function

```
void CUSBDlg::Pray(byte t, int i)
```

in KeybdProc?

if i try to using this function like this

```
LRESULT CALLBACK KeybdProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if ((nCode == HC_ACTION) && (wParam == WM_KEYDOWN))
    {
        KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT *pKey = (KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam;
        int key = pKey->vkCode;
        cout << key << " ";
        if (key == VK_INSERT)
        {
            SetDlgItemText(IDC_STATUSTEXT, "On")
            Pray(0x04, 6)
        }
        if (key == VK_DELETE)
        {
            SetDlgItemText(IDC_STATUSTEXT, "Off")
        }
    }
CallNextHookEx(KbHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
return 0;

}
```

the error "undeclared identifier"

somebody help me for fixing this problem X(

Comment: No reason to make `KbHook` global - the first argument to `CallNextHookEx` is ignored per the documentation. However, your problem looks like you don't know how to call a member function in C++, which has nothing to do with the Windows API, though the first code sample doesn't indicate where the problem happens and it's rather hard to test ourselves because this isn't a [mcve].

Comment: can you help me please :) ??

Comment: `CUSBDlg::Pray()`? Read a book, or two, and those artifacts will fade away. On a more serious note: No matter how much you pray, unless you have a firm grasp on C++ and the Windows API, your MFC endeavors will not end well.

Answer (score 1):

Your callback is not a non-static method of your dialog class, so it does not have a `this` pointer with which to call the [`CWnd::SetDlgItemText()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa250327.aspx) and `CUSBDlg::Prey()` methods.  You are getting an "undeclared identifier" error on `Prey()` because there is no function in scope with that name. And you are getting the "function does not take 2 parameters" error because the callback is trying to call the Win32 API [`SetDlgItemText()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645521.aspx) function, which is in scope but takes 3 parameters as input.

To solve both problems, you need to store a global pointer to your dialog so the callback can reach it when needed, eg:

```
CUSBDlg *Dlg;
HHOOK KbHook;

LRESULT CALLBACK KeybdProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if ((nCode == HC_ACTION) && (wParam == WM_KEYDOWN))
    {
        KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT *pKey = (KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam;
        int key = pKey->vkCode;
        cout << key << " ";
        if (key == VK_INSERT)
        {
            Dlg->SetDlgItemText(IDC_STATUSTEXT, "On")
            Dlg->Pray(0x04, 6)
        }
        if (key == VK_DELETE)
        {
            Dlg->SetDlgItemText(IDC_STATUSTEXT, "Off")
        }
    }

    CallNextHookEx(KbHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    return 0;
}

BOOL CUSBDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialog::OnInitDialog();

    ...

    Dlg = this;

    GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    KbHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, KeybdProc, hInstance, 0);

    ...
}
```